# Asp.net Mvc 6 Combine browse image and add image size image name into sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I saw this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1976497.aspx?ASP%20Net%20MVC%205%20Upload%20Image%20Save%20to%20Database%20Create%20Thumbnail%20and%20Display%20in%20View , which is a good example, but it does not apply for Asp.Net Mvc 6 because HttpPostedFileBase does not exist in Mvc 6. Does someone help me this code for Mvc 6.

// Controller code

```
public IActionResult Create(PublisherInfos publisherInfos, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //attach the uploaded image to the object before saving to Database
            file = Request.Form.Files.GetFile("CoverImage");

            //get posted file from web form
            var filename = publisherInfos.FileName;
            var filePathOriginal = _appEnv.ApplicationBasePath + "\\wwwroot\\images";
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePathOriginal, filename);
            file.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            //initialize file upload class to save file to wwwroot directory
            FormUpload upload = new FormUpload();

            //get the uploaded file name
            string Photo = upload.SaveFile(file);
            if (Photo != "")
            {
                Photo = Url.Content($"~/upload/{Photo}");
            }
            // Add file size and file name into Database
            _context.PublisherInfos.Add(publisherInfos);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = PublisherInfoMessageId.DataloadSuccess });

        }           

        return View(publisherInfos);
    }
```

// Then, class model as follows:
// FormUpload class

```
public class FormUpload
{
    private static string UploadDestination { get; set; }
    private static string[] AllowedExtensions { get; set; }

    IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv;

    public FormUpload()
    {

        //upload config
        FormUpload.AllowedExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif" };
        FormUpload.UploadDestination = _appEnv.ApplicationBasePath + "\\wwwroot\\images";
    }
    private bool VerifyFileExtension(string path)
    {
        return FormUpload.AllowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(path));
    }
    private bool VerifyFileSize(IFormFile file)
    {
        Double fileSize = 0;
        using (var reader = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            //get filesize in kb
            fileSize = (reader.Length / 1024);
        }
        //filesize less than 1MB => true, else => false
        return (fileSize < 1024) ? true : false;
    }
    public string SaveFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        string Filename = "";
        if (file.ContentDisposition != null)
        {
            //parse uploaded file
            var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
            Filename = parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
            string uploadPath = FormUpload.UploadDestination + Filename;

            //check extension
            bool extension = this.VerifyFileExtension(uploadPath);
            if (extension == false)
            {
                return "";
            }
            //check file size
            bool filesize = this.VerifyFileSize(file);
            if (filesize == false)
            {
                return "";
            }
            //save the file to upload destination
            file.SaveAs(uploadPath);
        }
        return Filename;
    }
}
```

// PublisherInfos model

```
public class PublisherInfos
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int PubInfoId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    [Display(Name = "Image Size")]
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }

    [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 8)]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(Max)")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Image Filename")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Image")]
    [Display(Name = "Book Cover")]
    public byte[] CoverImage { get; set; }

}
```

// Create of publisher info form

```html
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PublisherInfos</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PubId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="PubId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Publishers" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CoverImage" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                 <input name="CoverImage" class="form-control" />
                 <input type="file" class="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ImageSize" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="ImageSize" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageSize" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FileName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FileName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FileName" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

// ----------------------------------------
The above code, I worked for the Publishers Information Form to store the image in the CoverImage Field, the file size adding to the ImageSize Field and the file name storing in the FileName field. But I cannot get the result I want to store in the database in Asp.Net Mvc 6.
1. What is wrong to this code?
2. Can you help me to find the mistake?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Use "IFormFile" on the place of  HttpPostedFileBase